How to uncompile marshal.loads?
I have a .dat file that contains binary non-human readable values, if this value is read as binary with python and passed back to the marshal.loads function and then the result is passed to the exec function the script will execute.
import marshal 

file=open("myfile.dat", "rb")
file_content=file.read()
file.close()

file_content=marshal.loads(marshal.loads(file_content))
exec(file_content)

How can I uncompile/decompile this script?
I tried replacing exec with dis.dis but the output was just text (probably assembly code) but I need python code.

Do you really want to allow such an obvious arbitrary code execution?

I will execute it in a virtual environment

The term you want to search for is python decompiler. There is no perfect solution and nothing first party, but one of those might be good enough for your usecase.
